# Ionic reloading same page with animation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app using Ionic/Angular js. I have got a scenario like a page contains product list and when I tap on any product it will take you to product detail page. In product detail if I swap right it should go to previous product detail and If swap left then has to go to next product. It has to do an animation(LTR and RTL) whenever you swipe. What would be the best way to do it?

I tried reloading the same page but that doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two views, the product list view and product details view. This is a parent->child relationship, and by default the only swipe navigation option is a swipe to go back. You are essentially looking for a slidebox type interaction, but you want it to be a navigation tool and not just a slideshow component.

You will need to come up with your own swipe event listeners that can navigate. Something like this might get you going a little bit. Using the `ionic.on()` method you can listen for swipe events, and you will need to figure out a way to use `$state.go()` to navigate to the next item.

```
ionic.on('swipe-right', function() { $state.go('nextProduct'); }, document);
ionic.on('swipe-left', function() { $state.go('prevProduct'); }, document);
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.EventController/#onGesture

Comment: Thanks Wilken for your answer. I am able to make use of Ionic's swipe left & swipe right feature but the issue is how you make the view animation like RTL and LFR being on the same page?

Comment: You actually make them different pages, which means registering a lot of states for each of the pages. Each state will somehow need to know the prev/next link to go to when swiping. It will certainly take some creativity to flush this out.

Comment: I don't think its a good practice to go with that approach. I was able to resolve this by using simple CSS3 animation.

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle the history for the user. Adding lots of states makes it possible to use the back button in navigation and wires into the Ionic navigation.

Comment: Yep, thats right. So I am just using CSS3 animation to give a feel of page swipe left/right animation.